# Can I swap the close buttons from the left to the right?

Tags: navigation, window-management, user-interface

In elementary OS, as with Ubuntu and Mac OS X, the close button is on the left.

[image]

Can I change this to have the close button on the right?

Comment: it doesn't work for me, I tried both terminal instruction and installing dconf, but the buttons remain in the same format
Any help?

Comment: Is this the first question?

Comment: can you guys check my question please? these tricks dont work https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9026/dconf-editor-problem-no-changes?noredirect=1#comment11988_9026

Comment: Didn't work for me. Can you check my post please? https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9026/dconf-editor-problem-no-changes

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here is another approach without installing any additional software.
Open a terminal session and run one of the following commands:

#### Default Button Style

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.appearance button-layout close:maximize
```

[image]

#### Max and Close buttons switched

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.appearance button-layout maximize:close
```

[image]

#### Windows Button Style

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.appearance button-layout :minimize,maximize,close
```

[image]

#### Mac OS X Button Style

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.appearance button-layout close,minimize,maximize
```

[image]

You have to logout and login or restart to make the changes take effect.

Comment: Nice answer! Very thorough and the example images are a great visual help.

Comment: Did you restart or logoff afterwards?

Comment: When I try this solution on Mac OS High Siera I get: "No such schema ?org.pantheon.desktop.gala.appearance?" Did I miss something?

Answer (score 15):

Yes you can. First you need to install `dconf-editor` with:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Once it is installed, open it and search for the entry:

```
org/pantheon/desktop/gala/appearance/button-layout
```

There you'll see the dafault setting:

```
close:maximize
```

you can switch those as:

```
maximize:close
```

to have the close button to the right. You probably need to restart or log off and back in for the changes to take effect.

Comment: That's odd, you should be able to install it without having to add anything else: http://howtoelementaryos.org/how-to-install-dconf-tools-in-elementary-os

Comment: Aha, my universe source is disabled.

Comment: For me this doesn't work for windows with Headerbars. Only for Titelbar windows. Is there a second setting?

Answer (score 6):

You could also install elementary-tweaks

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

Open switchboard->Tweaks and change the window buttons there.

Comment: It's not recommended to use elementary tweaks as it is no longer maintained and has been known to break systems. It's also unsecure to add arbitrary PPAs and not necessary for this task.

Comment: It didn't break mine

Comment: @DanielForé I think you mean the older tweaks

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use elementary tweaks (not officially supported but easier to use).

Add Ken Hartley's ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:justsomedood/justsomeelementary
```

Don't forget to update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally install elementary-tweaks

```
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

Access elementary tweaks through System Settings (You will have to restart it if you had it open during installation).

In the `General > Appearance` tab, the option `Window Controls` should allow you to change the close button to the right.

Comment: Hey, Welcome to [elementaryos.se]! Here we use markdown, it's a way of formatting plain text that doesn't need html. So to add code simply surround it by `` (back ticks, below Esc) or indent by 4 spaces! Read http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/formatting for more info!

Comment: Beware that Tweaks is no longer supported (https://plus.google.com/u/0/+MichaelStarkweather/posts/Y8zixFDEWiv) and its use is actively discouraged by the dev team (http://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/38z164/what_is_the_elementary_teams_stance_on_elementary/crz5dsf)

Comment: Indeed, dconf-editor is still the best way.

Answer (score -1):

I just installed elementary OS to give it a try. From time to time, I always want to check if there is a real practical alternative (free) to Windows. Every time I've failed. Ubuntu = wrong GUI for my taste, Zorin = good, but utterly useless since has the wi-fi problem - keeps dropping, spent a day to fix it with no use. Now eOS.

All I want to do is to change minimize, maximize, close buttons to the right - windows style, since I do not intend to re-learn muscle memory. I have failed. I am using a Loki (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS xenial). I've tried:

- `gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.appearance button-layout :minimize,maximize,close` in the console, logged out, restarted etc
- `dconf-editor`, then went to `org > pantheon > desktop > gala > appearance`, then changed to `:minimize,maximize,close`. logged out, restarted etc
- I did not used any `tweaker`s for this, since everybody are complaining they are system breakers and lack any support.

Can anyone tell me if there is a workaround for this or I'll trow this distro (again) into the abyss?

later: found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1568490). **It's a Won't fix for systems based on > Ubuntu 14**. There's your answer. Well, goodbye to this distro. Again.