# Can I set an app window's width, height, and position from Terminal?

Tags: window-management, window-decoration

1. How can I set geometry for applications by console command?
2. How can I remove borders (title, close minimie maximize buttons) from application by console command?

For example, I want to start a windows in virtualbox and make a screencast. I want to set a precise position of virtualbox window and same precise position in screencast application.

Comment: *geometry*'s an interesting way to put it.

Comment: @Huey While perhaps strange from a computing perspective, it's technically correct. Geometry relates to both shape and relative position.

Comment: These are two seperate questions and should be split. I think I've got part 1 covered, part 2 is basically a theming question. [Removing / changing window control buttons is already answered elsewhere.](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-i-swap-the-close-buttons-from-the-left-to-the-right/)

Comment: Yes, part 1 about windows size is covered. But part 2 about remove window borders is not coved. Your link is about change buttons in all windows. Bu I want to remove full border with title for 1 window.

Comment: So you want only the window content, nothing else?

Answer (score 6):

## Using wmctrl

The program wmctrl allows to you to get infos and change the states of currently open windows. Install it by typing `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`.

Type `wmctrl -l` to output a list of currently managed windows:

```
0x02e00003 -1 username plank
0x02a00003 -1 username wingpanel
0x0340000a  0 username Home: wmctrl
0x0360000a  0 username Scratch
0x03403972  0 username Home: wmctrl
```

Now you can resize and move the window with `wmctrl -r <Window> -e <G>,<X>,<Y>,<W>,<H>`, for example `wmctrl -r Scratch -e 0,10,200,600,400`

`<X>`, `<Y>`, `<W>`, `<H>` can also be set to `-1` so the respective value stays the same.

If there are multiple windows with the same name, use the -i switch and input the window id instead of the title. This example will only change the dimensions of the second window called "Home: wmctrl" (a Terminal) `wmctrl -i -r 0x03403972 -e 0,10,20,-1,-1`

Or change the state with `wmctrol -r <Window> -b <State>`.

To learn about all options, type `wmctrl --help` or [`man wmctrl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/wmctrl.1.html).

## Saved state in gsettings

Most apps save the last position of their window in gsettings, unfortunately quite inconsistently. Some examples for elementary apps:

- Audience: No saved state.
- Calculator: No saved state.
- **Files** `org.pantheon.files.preferences`
  `maximized` (boolean), `window-height`, `window-width` (no x and y position)
- **Photos** `org.pantheon.foto.saved-state`
  `window-state`, `window-height`, `window-width` (no x and y position)
- **Calendar (Maya)** `org.pantheon.maya.saved-state`
  `window-state`, `window-height`, `window-width` (no x and y position)
- **Geary Mail** `org.yorba.geary`
  `window-state`, `window-height`, `window-width` (no x and y position)
- **Music (Noise)** `org.pantheon.noise.saved-state`
  `window-state`, `window-height`, `window-width` (no x and y position)
- **Scratch** `org.pantheon.scratch.saved-state`
  `window-state`, `window-height`, `window-width`, `window-x`, `window-y`
- **Sytem Settings (Switchboard)** `org.pantheon.switchboard.saved-state`
  `window-state`, `position`, `window-height`, `window-width`
- **Terminal** `org.pantheon.terminal.saved-state`
  `window-state`, `opening-x`, `opening-y`, `window-height`, `window-width`

You can get the current value of a key by typing the following in your Terminal:

`gsettings get org.pantheon.files.preferences window-height`

You can change the value by typing:

`gsettings set org.pantheon.files.preferences window-height 400`

Comment: I have opened a bug reports about [missing x & y](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1475823), [inconsistencies](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1475825) and [missing window states](https://bugs.launchpad.net/audience/+bug/1475826).