# How to put minimize and maximize button in elementary os loki

Tags: release-loki, elementary-project, minimize

I have been searching for a long time and a lot of people stated to go to appearance and windows cursor, but when I installed tweak tool I can't seem to find any of the "windows cursor"

[image]

Please help ASAP.

Comment: Also see http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1/5565

Answer (score 2):

You need to install elementary-Tweaks instead Gnome Tweak Tool, but maybe you can find that setting under the 'Windows' tab in the Tweak Tool. If not:

First run in a terminal this commands (you need to install `software-properties-common` to be able to add repositories):

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common && 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

After that, open system settings and select Tweaks, under the first panel you'll find the option to modify the window controls layout:

[image]

Comment: elementary tweaks is no longer maintained