# Dconf Editor problem - no changes

Tags: pantheon, dconf, minimize

As you can see in the picture below, I'm using Ubuntu with the Pantheon theme (from the Elementary OS). I can't seem to find an answer for my problem: I want to change the buttons (close, maximize and minimize) to the right corner of the screen and that is having no effect in here. Also, I seem to have a button (on the right side) that seems like the close button but it's not.

Any help please?[image: See the image here]

Comment: You can check this question. http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-i-swap-the-close-buttons-from-the-left-to-the-right

Comment: thanks for your help, but I've already done my research :/
dconf editor/gsetting it's the same and it doesnt work on my pc, so there is something wrong in here..
And unfortunately elementary-tweaks is a dead project and I cant get it nowadays

Comment: Installing themes in elementary OS is a much easier task thanks to elementary Tweaks tool. Until recently, elementary Tweaks was no longer maintained and hence elementary OS team advised not to use it . But it seems like someone has taken it up to him to maintain it. This means that now you can install elementary Tweaks in Loki easily using this PPA: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks Source: https://itsfoss.com/things-to-do-after-installing-elementary-os-loki/

Comment: I've already done it.. However, when I install it, I cant open System settings.. Only when I remove it I can open it back

Comment: Maybe I'm installing it from the wrong repository??

Comment: Ken Hartley's ppa is obsolete. Elementary-tweaks users are using Phillip Scott repository in elementary OS 0.4 (Loki). I don't  use it myself as I'm satisfied with the default settings and didn't want to mess with settings (I prefer to adapt to what elementary has set). I respect those who want more personalization as I understand is your case.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far :)!
So if all people use it, either I am with a problem in my system somewhere else OR when installing elementary-tweaks he doesnt download from Phillip Scott's repository.. Any idea how to check this??

Comment: The easiest way is to remove any other repository that you have added in order to download elementary-tweaks so there is no chance of mistake. I'm sure there are more methods to choose ppa priority  but in your case this is the simplest solution. http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-do-i-remove-a-ppa

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, when installing elementary-tweaks, my System Settings doesnt work and it end up crashing.