# Can I swap the close bottons from left to right: Gnome

Tags: user-interface, microsoft-windows, navigation

Just like [this post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-i-swap-the-close-buttons-from-the-left-to-the-right) I have been traditionally a windows user and would like to have my buttons on the right hand side.

I couldn't find **org.pantheon.desktop.gala.appearance button-layout** but did have **org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout**. I changed the settings to **':minimize,maximize,close'* logged out and nothing and then restarted and nothing. The settings are there but have not taken effect.

Im on **OS X El Capitan** and used the **gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout :minimize,maximize,close** command. I have read online that this particular version was designed to block customization much more than previously available and have not been able to find a working solution online.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

### Installing elementary tweaks would be an easy graphical solution of customizing your system.

Here's a link to the git repo https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks

It is true that elementary os loki does block customization by not having the
software-properties-common package preinstalled. Without this package you cannot a PPA to your system.

#### Installing elementary-tweaks

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks

Comment: Im on OS X which does not have apt-get. I do have brew is there is an alternate solution with that tool.

Comment: I installed Fink as a work around for sudo apt-get but I had serious problems with my work firewall and the program so I removed it. So there is a way to get sudo apt-get but it takes several extra tools to get it going.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/DialogsUseHeader': <0>, 'Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu': <0>, 'Gtk/DecorationLayout': <':close,minimize,maximize'>}"
```

from terminal.

Comment: org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings does not exist.